# Best way to simulate a load in Circuit Simulator

Tags: mosfet, current, simulation

I'm a bit new to simulating circuits and I'm looking for advice on the best way to simulate a load. I'm trying to build a current limiting circuit, using a current sense resistor and a set of transistors. The end application that I have will probably exceed the current limit of the transistors, so I'm trying to replace them with MOSFETs.

The issue I have is trying to find a good way to simulate varying loads drawing too much power, so I can trigger the current sense transistor to shut off the circuit.

I tried using different value resistors where the load is, but I don't think that's an accurate simulation.

Any advice? Thank you!

[image: Current limiting circuit]

Comment: what do you think is wrong with using a resistor?

Comment: @prasanna Please ask a specific question

Comment: @VoltageSpike - would a resistor be an accurate model of power draw? What I'm trying to do is simulate different power levels to see when the circuit shuts off. But my simulations don't seem to be working properly - so I figured I must have been modeling the load incorrectly

Comment: Please edit the question, with the specific question, thanks

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with simulating a load using a fixed resistor, except that it forces you to perform several individual simulations, changing the resistance each time, to build up a graph of behaviour vs load.

If you're asking about how to automate load variation during a single simulation, then there are a few components that simulators provide to help with this. They include:

- **Voltage Controlled Voltage Source** (VCVS): a voltage source component
  that varies its EMF as a function of some applied potential
  difference.
- **Voltage Controlled Current Source** (VCCS): a current source component
  that varies its current as a function of some applied potential
  difference.
- **Current Controlled Voltage Source** (CCVS): a voltage source component
  that varies its EMF as a function of some current elsewhere in
  the circuit.
- **Current Controlled Current Source** (CCCS): a current source component
  that varies its current as a function of some current elsewhere in
  the circuit.
- **Voltage Controlled Switch**: a switch whose open/closed state depends
  on some applied potential difference.
- **Time Controlled Switch**: a switch whose open/closed state changes at
  some fixed point in time.

<sub>Quick disclaimer: What I suggest below is just an example. There are probably better ways to do all this, but in a pinch this is how I've automated a couple of simulations of my own projects.</sub>

If those devices aren't directly suitable, then you can create other clever compound-components using them. For example, what you are asking for might be a "voltage controlled resistor" (VCR). [This web page](http://www.ecircuitcenter.com/Circuits/vc_resistor1/vc_resistor1.htm) inspired a [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/) model to do that:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffSL8S.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Essentially we use the fact that a resistor develops a voltage in proportion to the current through it. To model this I employ a voltage source whose voltage is proportional to the very current it is passing, and we vary the effective resistance by pre-multiplying that current by some other control signal.

In the that circuit I use the VCR model in combination with a "comma-separated-values" voltage source to create a linearly rising voltage from 0V to 1V. This allows me to perform a time-domain simulation in which the effective resistance between VCR1A and VCR1B varies from 0Ω to 1kΩ. I place that resistance in the feedback path of an inverting amplifier, where it is effectively controlling the gain. Here's what the output looks like, when the input is a sinusoid:

[image]

Here's how you might implement such a VCR in your application:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmMNV5.png)</sup>

I'm not sure if I should spoil your fun by including the simulation results, so I'll leave you to try it for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem modeling a resistive load with a resistor. This circuit wil produce ~45mA current limit to any load (R2). As long as you have the 5V signal on the input, the circuit will provide the current to load limited to ~45mA. If the input voltage goes to 0V, the current will go to zero (ignoring any leakage currents). You should not need to go to a MOSFET at 45mA current but I used one in my illustration just so you can see how it behaves. Your original circuit runs at about 50mA with two 2N3904 transistors. Since the MOSFET that I used has a relatively high threshold voltage, the turn on characteristics are quite different.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAU8Pz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>